# Searching by ID shows error when ID is integer

Tags: java, swing, jpa

I attempt to Search Item by Name and Id. When search by Id shows error like below. When I read it line number 606 is the place where is wrong.(I assume ) That line is

`q.setParameter("itemid","%"+jTextField10.getText()+"%");`

Thanks in advance to Help me to solve this problem.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have 
attempted to set a value of type class java.lang.String for parameter itemid with expected type of 
class java.lang.Integer from query string SELECT t FROM Tblitem t WHERE t.itemid like :itemid.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.setParameterInternal(QueryImpl.java:933)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:593)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:1)
at pos.Sales_UI.jTextField10KeyReleased(Sales_UI.java:606)
at pos.Sales_UI.access$500(Sales_UI.java:9)
at pos.Sales_UI$6.keyReleased(Sales_UI.java:303)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6496)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2832)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6312)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4762)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

JTextField Key release event is shown below

```
private void jTextField10KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         
if(jRadioButton1.isSelected()){
    Query q = POSHardwarePUEntityManager.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Tblitem t WHERE t.itemname 
like :itemname");
    q.setParameter("itemname","%"+jTextField10.getText()+"%");
    tblitemList.clear();
    tblitemList = q.getResultList();
    refreshTable(tblitemList);
}else if(jRadioButton2.isSelected()){
    Query q = POSHardwarePUEntityManager.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Tblitem t WHERE t.itemid like 
:itemid");
    q.setParameter("itemid","%"+jTextField10.getText()+"%");
    tblitemList.clear();
    tblitemList = q.getResultList();
    refreshTable(tblitemList);
}else
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Select an Option to Search");
```

}

TblItem Entity Class is below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBLITEM")
@XmlRootElement

public class Tblitem implements Serializable {

@Transient
private PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ITEMID")
private Integer itemid;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ITEMNAME")
private String itemname;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ITEMUNIT")
private String itemunit;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ITEMRATE")
private double itemrate;
```

Comment: How do you expect a `like` to work on a number? I mean, what result would you expect?

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca , I attempt to changing that with = also like below           
 "SELECT t FROM Tblitem t WHERE t.itemid = :itemid" but not work

Comment: because you need to convert that string to an integer (for example with `Integer.parseInt(jTextField10.getText())` which, of course, will fail if the text field doesn't contain a number.

Comment: @ Federico klez Culloca, Tks I tried as your answer like below q.setParameter("itemid","%"+Integer.parseInt(jTextField10.getText())+"%");

Comment: I already commented down on Jim's answer. Lose those `%`s.

Comment: @ Federico klez Culloca . I found the error. Tks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `LIKE` with a field that is stored as an integer in the database.

In addition, when you set the parameter for `itemid` you must provide an `int` or `Integer` value, not a `String`.

Comment: I change like this q.setParameter("itemid","%"+Integer.parseInt(jTextField10.getText())+"%"); also shows same error

Comment: @tharinduhd You're still using `"%"` around the field value.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca, Yes I got your point  Tks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you should be able to use `CAST` or `CONVERT` functions to convert the integer field into string and then apply `LIKE` operator to this converted value.

However, this could be a severe performance hit if the table is large enough because `LIKE` with the wildcard would require full table scan.

```java
Query q = POSHardwarePUEntityManager.createQuery(
    "SELECT t FROM Tblitem t WHERE CAST(t.itemid AS CHAR(10)) like :itemid");
q.setParameter("itemid","%"+jTextField10.getText()+"%");
```

If you have decided to search by the integer value, the query and parameter should look like this (assuming that `jTextField10` contains a valid integer):

```java
Query q = POSHardwarePUEntityManager.createQuery(
    "SELECT t FROM Tblitem t WHERE t.itemid = :itemid");
q.setParameter("itemid", Integer.parseInt(jTextField10.getText()));
```